# The state is not saved when whitelist of redux-persist is updated

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

#### I updated my redux-persist whitelist by adding one more reducer , the state is not saved even after changing for the new reducer added. However the state is saved for the previous reducer.

> I tried checking for the updated state by refreshing.(cmd + R ->ios)

```
    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
      whitelist: ['user'],
    };

    const persistedReducer = persistCombineReducers (persistConfig, reducers);

    const middlewares = [promiseMiddleware (), thunk];

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    if (__DEV__) {
      middlewares.push (createLogger ());
    }

    export default () => {
      const store = createStore (
        persistedReducer,
        undefined,
        compose (applyMiddleware (...middlewares))
      );
      const persistor = persistStore (store);
      return {store, persistor};
    };
```

#### Before updating the code , the state for user is persisting

```
    const persistConfig = {
      key: 'root',
      storage,
      whitelist: ['user', 'home'],
    };

    const persistedReducer = persistCombineReducers (persistConfig, reducers);

    const middlewares = [promiseMiddleware (), thunk];

    // eslint-disable-next-line
    if (__DEV__) {
      middlewares.push (createLogger ());
    }

    export default () => {
      const store = createStore (
        persistedReducer,
        undefined,
        compose (applyMiddleware (...middlewares))
      );
      const persistor = persistStore (store);
      return {store, persistor};
    };
```

#### Here after updating the whitelist , the state is not saved for home reducer.

Comment: Check this thread and see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333565/redux-persist-blacklist-being-ignored/54338685#54338685

Comment: Thanks for the reply. will definitely check it out .